# How to bind port 4200 (Angular web server) to port 80 (Apache web server)?

Tags: linux, angular, apache, port

I have Apache Web Server running on EC2 (RHEL 7) on port `80`.

Also have Angular App running on port `4200` on the same server.

How to bind port 80 so that when someone from outside goes to IP (e.g. `1.2.3.4`) goes directly to Apache port 80 (that part works now) which then redirect (or bind) to port `4200` so that the end user can see Angular app output (instead of Apache output)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reverse proxy Nginx for example.
The step will be the following: Nginx listens 80 port from outside and passes this request to 4200 to your Angular app. 
Why do you use apache on this port? And what does apache do?

Comment: I had troubles installing Nginx (corporate server with restricted access to internet and different yum repositories etc.) so since Apache is already working - trying to see to make it with that. Apache is also a Web server (similar functions as Nginx). Not sure if can sert reverse proxy with Apache (similar like you are suggesting for Nginx)...

Answer (score 0):

You should instead like Red Cricket says follow the docs.

First run `ng build prod` or whatever build you need.

Then add the `.htaccess` file with redirect rules into your `dist` folder and place it wherever your apache will serve the angular app.

For extra details see the link provided by Red Cricket.